# what timestamp format is this

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a timestamp exported from a program that I'm not sure how to convert programmatically using c#

I can get more examples if required

any pointers would be appreciated

1280833200 ==  3 aug 2010 12:00

thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - the number of seconds since midnight UTC on 1st January 1970. You can use [this site](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) to convert the timestamp to an ordinary date and time.

As for conversion in C#, this should work:

```
double timestamp = 1280833200;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
```

Comment: Cheers, First CORRECT answer :-) much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

isnt that the datetime in <strike>ticks</strike> [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

edit: yes it is: http://www.epochconverter.com/

You can make a `DateTime` by adding those seconds to a new date.

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(1280833200)
```

Comment: The "ticks" in a .NET timestamp are "the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar" according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx, which is not the same measurement or epoch as a Unix timestamp.

Comment: Nope, a tick is 100 nanoseconds, and the 'epoch' is the year 1. 1280833200 is a Unix timestamp (seconds since midnight on 1970-01-01).

Comment: @p.campbell why did you edit a wrong answer to fix it instead of just upvoting a correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Unix timestamp; number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. You can convert like:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
DateTime ts = epoch.AddSeconds(1280833200);
```

Comment: @foz I think I beat Richard by about 30 seconds, actually . . . but I'm glad you accepted a correct answer :)

Comment: not sure, I remember seeing yours said it was a minute later! anyhow, thanks to both of you.